# What's the sequence in the below 2 grids?

Tags: number-sequence

The sequences are different in each grid, can you solve all 4 question marks?

Grid 1:
[image]

Grid 2:
[image]

Note: Since it are 2 seperate grids, the sequence logic is different.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to the first grid is as follows

> [image]

Reasoning

> Reading the existing grid top-to-bottom and left-to-right gives the sequence $4,8,2,6,2,2,4,8$
>  We notice that from the 3rd element onwards each number is the product of the previous two modulo $10$,
>  e.g, $2 \times 6 = 12 \equiv 2\mod 10$
>  This means that the next element at the top is $4 \times 8 = 32 \equiv \textbf{2}\mod 10$
>  and the next element at the bottom is $8 \times 2 = 16 \equiv \textbf{6}\mod 10$

Less certain, but I think the answer to the second grid is as follows

> [image]

Reasoning

> This time let us read each column as a single number by concatenating the digits i.e, $89, 18, 16, 12$
>  In this sequence, each number is just double the second digit (bottom digit) of the previous number,
>  e.g, $9 \times 2 = 18, 8 \times 2 = 16$
>  This means the next two-digit number is $2 \times 2 = 4 = 04$.